# trouble in tabwidget android id

Tags: android, xml, tabs, android-studio

I am working in android studio.
Here, I have a  in my main.xml. When the android:id attribute is set to "@+id/tabs", I get an error "cannot resolve directory @+id".

```
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/createTab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
```

I think, i have made some sort of reference to some file from this text"@+id/tabs", where AS gives code completion options to select from the data is, if it does not reckon it.

please, explain what is happening and How do I get the app working again?

Comment: Go to `files -> invalidate cashes/restart` in android-studio

Comment: Try changing this : `android:id="@+id/tabs"` to :   `android:id="@android:id/tabs"`

Comment: @Josef
It doesn't work, I tried them both.